# Accordion Jquery and page height in ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

ok so I'm calling in a page via ajax and animating it's height which is working wonderfully, next I have a accordion like function to toggle the visibility of an element and then additionally adjust the height of the containing element which does not work. 
Why?

```
function accordionfaq(){
    $('.question_all').on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        /* Act on the event */
        var newHeight = $('.faq').height();  //new height
        $(this).children('.answer').toggle('slow', function(){
            $('#loadplace').delay(200).animate({
                height:newHeight
            }).fadeIn();
        });
    });
}
```

jsfiddle with complete code and error: 
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vimes1984/VykFs/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the problem here was that i was defining the height before the toggle event... I am dumb at times...: 
fixed code here:

```
function accordionfaq(){
    $('.question_all').on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        /* Act on the event */
        $(this).children('.answer').toggle('slow', function(){

            var newHeight = $('.faq').height();  //THIS NEEDS TO go in here!!! not outside... 

            $('#loadplace').delay(200).animate({
                height:newHeight
            }).fadeIn();
        });
    });
}
```